# Why is my Datashader plot saved from HoloViews such a low resolution?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to save plots, generated with holoviews using the bokeh backend, to a png. To do this I'm using the following code

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade

curve: hv.Curve = hv.Curve(__some_data_for_curve__)
hv.save(datashade(curve), output_path, backend=bokeh)
```

Unfortunately the saved png is not rendered properly:

[image: Unfinished Rendered Plot]

When I instead use

```
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade

curve: hv.Curve = hv.Curve(__some_data_for_curve__)
pn.serve(datashade(curve))
```

I get a nicely rendered Plot:

[image: Finished Rendered Plot]

This leads to the assumption that datashader does not properly render the image when just saving the plot to file. Does anybody have an idea on how to get datashader to finish rendering before saving?

Comment: Could you please point out why you think the first plot is not correctly rendered? As fas as I see is the difference between this two figures the y-range/zoom.

Comment: It would be good to update the title of this issue to "Setting the resolution of Datashader output saved from HoloViews" or "Why is my Datashader plot saved from HoloViews such a low resolution?".

Comment: @mosc9575, if you expand both plots on your screen you'll see that the top plot is a pixelated, low-resolution version of the bottom one, even though they look the same from a distance.

Answer (score 2):

Good question about a subtle issue.

What's happening is that `hv.save` exports the "initial" rendering of a HoloViews object, before any subsequent hooks or streams take effect. The initial rendering includes an RGB image that is the result of HoloViews calling Datashader with initial height and width values determined by arguments to the `datashade` call (`height=400` and `width=400` by default). When you are viewing the plot interactively, the initial call is soon updated and overwritten with the size of the actual frame used in the plot as it gets laid out on your screen. Because your screen is usually much larger than 400x400, you won't normally even see the low-res version unless you save the file.

The other issue is that the default height and width are deliberately set to relatively low values, in order not to waste much time on a plot that most users will never see.

If you want the initial save to use a higher resolution, you can add arguments to the `datashade` call with specific values like `height=400, width=1024` or you can just tell it "scale up by 4X" using `pixel_ratio=4`.

You can also set those parameters globally at the start of your script or notebook, if you always want high-res exports:

```
from holoviews.operation.datashader import ResamplingOperation
ResamplingOperation.width=1000
ResamplingOperation.height=1000
ResamplingOperation.pixel_ratio=2
```

Or if you *always* want higher res, you can put those settings into your `~/.config/holoviews/holoviews.rc` file.

Comment: Many thanks. Adjusting the heigth and width already in the datashader did the trick. The pixle_ratio brings its own problems depending on the underlying data, so I'm gonna skip that one, even if this may do the job in most cases.

Comment: Great! The supplied `height` and `width` are always multiplied by the supplied `pixel_ratio` to get the actual width, so it shouldn't ever matter which one you choose to adjust. If there ever were such a difference, please file a reproducible bug report and we can check it out.